# Illegal character in query for post http

Tags: java, android, web-services, http

I'm facing problem with post http link for web-service

so i have used to encode pic to 64 byte coding to send it to web-service

the problem in img parameter but there is no spaces

can any one help me to reslove this problem?

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query at index 204: http://ictfox.com/Hafil_Updates/SchoolLocation_Insert.aspx?schoolId=212&Location_Longitude=0&Location_Latitude=0&Location_Image=/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEB
```

this is my class code :

```
                File file = new File(picturePath);
            // Get image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(file), null, o);

            // The new size we want to scale to
            final int MIN_SIZE = 70;

            // Find the correct scale value.
            int scale = 1;
            while (((o.outWidth / scale) >> 1) >= MIN_SIZE
                    && ((o.outHeight / scale) >> 1) >= MIN_SIZE) {
                scale <<= 1;
            }

            BitmapFactory.Options opts2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            opts2.inSampleSize = scale;



            try {
                // Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile();

                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(file), null,
                        opts2).compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos); // bm
                                                                                // is
                                                                                // the
                                                                                // bitmap
                                                                                // object
                BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(file), null,
                        opts2).recycle();
                byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
                imageString = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);

                Log.d("Http Response:",imageString);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.d("Http Response:", e.toString());
                }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
              Log.d("Http Response:", e.toString());
        }



    String date2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-ddhh:mm:ss",Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());

    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    httpClient.getParams().setParameter(ClientPNames.COOKIE_POLICY, CookiePolicy.BROWSER_COMPATIBILITY);
    // Creating HTTP Post
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://ictfox.com/Hafil_Updates/SchoolLocation_Insert.aspx?schoolId="+((MyApplication) mActivity.getApplication()).schoolNum+"&Location_Longitude="+this.txtLag+"&Location_Latitude="+this.txtLat+"&Location_Image="+imageString+"&Action_Date="+date2);




    02-25 19:56:13.103: D/GestureDetector(29778): [Surface Touch Event] mSweepDown False, mLRSDCnt : -1 mTouchCnt : 5 mFalseSizeCnt:0
02-25 19:56:13.608: D/SensorManager(29778): unregisterListener:: Trklfufi 9 budiwrd5mrfo5WirfulblrwuFmfulTrklfufi$KfukwiFmfulTrklfufiRvht@,*:bb+)(
02-25 19:56:13.613: D/Sensors(29778): Remain listener = Sending .. normal delay 200ms
02-25 19:56:13.613: I/Sensors(29778): sendDelay --- 200000000
02-25 19:56:13.628: D/SensorManager(29778): JNI - sendDelay
02-25 19:56:13.633: I/SensorManager(29778): Set normal delay = true
02-25 19:56:15.773: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(29778): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
02-25 19:56:46.398: D/(29778): Device driver API match
02-25 19:56:46.398: D/(29778): Device driver API version: 10
02-25 19:56:46.398: D/(29778): User space API version: 10 
02-25 19:56:46.403: D/(29778): mali: REVISION=Linux-r2p4-02rel0 BUILD_DATE=Thu Oct 25 08:43:05 KST 2012 
02-25 19:56:46.508: E/SensorManager(29778): thread start
02-25 19:56:46.513: D/SensorManager(29778): registerListener :: handle = 0  name= K3DH Acceleration Sensor delay= 200000 Trklfufi 9 budiwrd5mrfo5WirfulblrwuFmfulTrklfufi$KfukwiFmfulTrklfufiRvht@,*:bb+)(
02-25 19:56:49.943: D/GestureDetector(29778): [Surface Touch Event] mSweepDown False, mLRSDCnt : -1 mTouchCnt : 3 mFalseSizeCnt:0
02-25 19:56:52.628: D/GestureDetector(29778): [Surface Touch Event] mSweepDown False, mLRSDCnt : -1 mTouchCnt : 4 mFalseSizeCnt:0
02-25 19:56:52.713: D/ProgressBar(29778): setProgress = 0
02-25 19:56:52.713: D/ProgressBar(29778): setProgress = 0, fromUser = false
02-25 19:56:52.713: D/ProgressBar(29778): mProgress = 0mIndeterminate = false, mMin = 0, mMax = 10000
02-25 19:56:53.093: D/SensorManager(29778): unregisterListener:: Trklfufi 9 budiwrd5mrfo5WirfulblrwuFmfulTrklfufi$KfukwiFmfulTrklfufiRvht@,*:bb+)(
02-25 19:56:53.098: D/Sensors(29778): Remain listener = Sending .. normal delay 200ms
02-25 19:56:53.098: I/Sensors(29778): sendDelay --- 200000000
02-25 19:56:53.098: D/SensorManager(29778): JNI - sendDelay
02-25 19:56:53.098: I/SensorManager(29778): Set normal delay = true
02-25 19:56:53.823: D/Http Response:(29778): /9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEB
02-25 19:56:53.823: D/Http Response:(29778): AQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQH/2wBDAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEB
02-25 19:56:53.823: D/Http Response:(29778): AQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQH/wAARCABLAGQDASIA
02-25 19:56:53.823: D/Http Response:(29778): AhEBAxEB/8QAHwAAAQUBAQEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL/8QAtRAAAgEDAwIEAwUFBAQA
02-25 19:56:53.823: D/Http Response:(29778): AAF9AQIDAAQRBRIhMUEGE1FhByJxFDKBkaEII0KxwRVS0fAkM2JyggkKFhcYGRolJicoKSo0NTY3
02-25 19:56:53.823: D/Http Response:(29778): ODk6Q0RFRkdISUpTVFVWV1hZWmNkZWZnaGlqc3R1dnd4eXqDhIWGh4iJipKTlJWWl5iZmqKjpKWm
02-25 19:56:53.823: D/Http Response:(29778): p6ipqrKztLW2t7i5usLDxMXGx8jJytLT1NXW19jZ2uHi4+Tl5ufo6erx8vP09fb3+Pn6/8QAHwEA
02-25 19:56:53.823: D/Http Response:(29778): AwEBAQEBAQEBAQAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL/8QAtREAAgECBAQDBAcFBAQAAQJ3AAECAxEEBSEx
02-25 19:56:53.823: D/Http Response:(29778): BhJBUQdhcRMiMoEIFEKRobHBCSMzUvAVYnLRChYkNOEl8RcYGRomJygpKjU2Nzg5OkNERUZHSElK
02-25 19:56:53.823: D/Http Response:(29778): U1RVVldYWVpjZGVmZ2hpanN0dXZ3eHl6goOEhYaHiImKkpOUlZaXmJmaoqOkpaanqKmqsrO0tba3
02-25 19:56:53.823: D/Http Response:(29778): uLm6wsPExcbHyMnK0tPU1dbX2Nna4uPk5ebn6Onq8vP09fb3+Pn6/9oADAMBAAIRAxEAPwD+zn4p
02-25 19:56:53.823: D/Http Response:(29778): fEy+8A3WlRw2Bnt7u7SGeYFlEUZL/MAoYux2n5SME7gGDdfLf2rf2mdQ+A/wF1f4neG9Ih17VLG1
02-25 19:56:53.823: D/Http Response:(29778): tJ4rCSSRYzC86rczyGCOSQi1hEkuxF3yMojVlJzTfjv4z0jVdYh0CEo/9mOJLyXK4WXawWFeT8wB
02-25 19:56:53.823: D/Http Response:(29778): DseoG0Ec5r5P+NPiTw/J8LvEFl4puhLolvptyGt7lswrH5UpdWRz8ygYCochSTgYHP8AiT4pftB8
02-25 19:56:53.823: D/Http Response:(29778): 88KvpLeK/AORQx3iXw3iKvDXDvDVDAyweEw/C/F1KSwme5dQxMKDnj6NWrO1WrOdaths0pV8JCm6
02-25 19:56:53.823: D/Http Response:(29778): Sml/Yfhh4bZFmdfwzxmfcMSx1GnnGDr55lN68anEGW1cZTlHCylTaqUpYilHk/duLdOUZXbab98/
02-25 19:56:53.823: D/Http Response:(29778): Yz/by8F/tGeB7zVtZvtN0PX9MkSHUrE3amN9yeZHc2ryOjyW0oUMG6q3mRNh0YlPiL+2J4dvdR8V
02-25 19:56:53.823: D/Http Response:(29778): eBvDOuWw1JrSaHRbmyu1eWbUY4rh1SMox2tG0akKGJb5hjgmv5afgTo3iXxt4+8QeG/gzDqclpJq
02-25 19:56:53.823: D/Http Response:(29778): V5KselXU1nb22myXk7RrcXEUiBLdiGaOHkAF0RCqNX6OfC34Q+KfDfxY8IeFvEemTafrM11Hqz3s
02-25 19:56:53.823: D/Http Response:(29778): shntk03T3M+pXhuMAsI4dwIfDSSywxBnLZr/AEYhm3G3FGJ4BxWDzTOckoZTn+VZjmWHweGw0qnE
02-25 19:56:53.823: D/Http Response:(29778): UJXjHh/NZV8PXVKjKdWM6ywUqVapiaFKH1h0HVpT/rPxm+hj4J8KZn4lYifFM8mwWZcJ5tmuW8L1
02-25 19:56:53.823: D/Http Response:(29778): auFw+P4UwTyrE18RmOIq1MXPERw+BjGdVTlTvRoQnL2s3CFU/oB+FH7R3hTxD4A0XWPEmoRWmpE2
02-25 19:56:53.823: D/Http Response:(29778): 2nX3DMsl46v5EyhMkLej50AyolLwjLKM9n8TPiff6N4G1bWPAugah4q1xbKWTSNJtfItpL26KSfZ
02-25 19:56:53.823: D/Http Response:(29778): 4vNv57WKJXcJueWRVQMSzYWvkP4fjwt4D0S00fTZI4UQMQwO+6nCHLn92GdljGOVBCA5LDG4+sWX
02-25 19:56:53.823: D/Http Response:(29778): ivRZoRKbmKWN1DLIkqsGXMgO192DgrhsZ5BU4JGf7SzrgeGJzLM55fjK+Cy7ETcsJQhhISxWFjU5
02-25 19:56:53.823: D/Http Response:(29778): 00qjqyhyqXM6CdJuMbRlKThJv/B/w+8asJlnDfCkOJMgwnEPE2VxoxzzF189q0shzp4apFU08LRw
02-25 19:56:53.823: D/Http Response:(29778): NLGxlWpKMcdUhjoe1nOdaj7FShGPzN+z/wDHr9sKPXfH1/8AtAeArbwpoDXWl2PgiKWbTZZm1C9b
02-25 19:56:53.823: D/Http Response:(29778): UJrszNpOrakG02xs7f5JLowS3F8BbZRJ4nXzj9p39rDx34QlTT/CtlqOpX105UyWlpc3+oXMhcht
02-25 19:56:53.823: D/Http Response:(29778): sdrFNLs82WNI4YI1iEjxQxJkhG90+PnjjRLPwpZLa6nDDfprem3MNvvXfdW6NdW9xhC2fLhFykzu
02-25 19:56:53.823: D/Http Response:(29778): y7R8ibhIVJ8v0f4f2vxW1bwd4l0i2vr6bw74m8L+JLq4sT5dosvh7XtL1ptMu712W3IvW09IpLSa
02-25 19:56:53.823: D/Http Response:(29778): UMY3jmKMsZYebknCtDhyccJi8Tjcwp8/tZ4vMYqVfkqOVlJQdFOmpwlazTSaV5JKJ/onwN4kZHxx
02-25 19:56:53.823: D/Http Response:(29778): wTxL475Z4R8FRx+VrNcowvAvD+JxuX8NVs44fyfKq2CwksVjY5rWoV80oYmnipc6ruvmFdqKvUpq
02-25 19:56:53.823: D/Http Response:(29778): P562n7cHxjttZ/sebTfEC+IkuYoIdFuNM1ax1xbx5GWGCPTri1iv1uHYqsaJH5rMflUknP8ARX8C
02-25 19:56:53.823: D/Http Response:(29778): bv4g658Gfh9q/wAU9MOkeOdR8P295r+mMrC5tJp5ZpLOHUEkAZNTGntaHVIW5i1I3UWcLmvRo/E3
02-25 19:56:53.823: D/Http Response:(29778): hljG1z5du4WPE1zZkIh+cf68xsEVck73ZUCqzFgBmvLfGvxv0fSPtFr4ea3vniBE2rTFn02Ft0ij
02-25 19:56:53.823: D/Http Response:(29778): 7Msbhr1sjCsGWIsyiNpScDjxzq5zKnRwuSrAumuarUdSfJyJSXNKpUhThTp6OTTcm20oyb5k/mvE
02-25 19:56:53.823: D/Http Response:(29778): vxBn4pYfJ8syjwxy/g+pga8sVicdh6zrzxDdKpRVOOIeW5fHCYO7dWeGf1ipVrRotT5qdpepzQbQ
02-25 19:56:53.823: D/Http Response:(29778): 2cADnd2wN+SSewHXOTggHgZPwv4o+P8A8RrLxD4z0e28E2FvBo2vato2mz3bvKbqwsdRmtbPWopE
02-25 19:56:53.823: D/Http Response:(29778): vY45v7Ss0W9SBlKxfaIoZAZIJ0futa1HxjrtlLf6xqE8sDW5ujpaahBb3BtgWYlNJieNH4/1YZmk
02-25 19:56:53.823: D/Http Response:(29778): Y7QrM4IrwDVPEXgo2wuotQSaKVFkjaN8qysWPzbuVbJwQcMCCG2kE1HCdLhrNK2OVDMsqz+pho06
02-25 19:56:53.823: D/Http Response:(29778): dbDYOtLELBznUbp1Kk6NWLcavsqkKcpQ9nL9441JWnE+W4d4WoUJVpZlhqOaznCEIU40MQ6WHnGp
02-25 19:56:53.823: D/Http Response:(29778): GbnGftaSq88YcsoulZJy5ZKLnf274L/Eqbx54Fj1/wAenR/CviD+2vEOmzaXdajY2dy9jputXlpp
02-25 19:56:53.823: D/Http Response:(29778): moTWktzugfULGOC6wuIpFdbiFEilWIFfGF/4s8Gfapf3w7ZO8qTywyQDjoq/hjOTySvcr8E4atiK
02-25 19:56:53.823: D/Http Response:(29778): 9anXrYenVqzqQoQwblCjGc5SjSjJ1ryjBNRi3q1a6blI9DFeH1LE4rE4ijUr4SlXrVKtPC08KnSw
02-25 19:56:53.823: D/Http Response:(29778): 8KlSpKNGm5VW+Smnyxvryxjdton8U+Jbix8d+KJLrdJNFqOoGJWG52dbkqmxG++4gBMYPUHIPy18
02-25 19:56:53.823: D/Http Response:(29778): D/8ABRX4lalb/AHxJ/YiXcc89peeVI8RS4FqtrLvMrICMLnKjuQDgsQK+4fi5PpWpfETxNc6c6Pb
02-25 19:56:53.823: D/Http Response:(29778): vf8AmBoiColUbXKFWYA7kGQScP34avmb9obS9K8bfD3UtCNiJC9nIshlCvlikgYJwdwbAPO0EkZA
02-25 19:56:53.823: D/Http Response:(29778): 3ZP/ADD+HXivwNwHnfiXwLxHhcixs8D4zYriHL+JamWvMsbn0afFeIp1pxxUIT5J0qeFp4uniKlX
02-25 19:56:53.823: D/Http Response:(29778): kSqqcXJ0KtSf+jfg3Ry3LOOvC/ivH5fXrYfASySvjctm408NTjD6tVvUUovmknzRsk20pRu03f8A
02-25 19:56:53.823: D/Http Response:(29778): P7/gnzqS/s2fBnUfjH8Sdd0qw0Hx7JbX1rf+YBeaZYyhbW3EtxIwXeTGbqVAB9mMpTDNE5f7j8Ef
02-25 19:56:53.823: D/Http Response:(29778): tgeA/jR4s8Y6x4Hvhqdl4J0zRdBGuupP2mXWJ7ie6+zzkAzq0dnB58sZ2M5VASRKo/mp+MMvj7wX
02-25 19:56:53.823: D/Http Response:(29778): fX3wyuvE2tyeDLW7ku9I0Ca9uDpcMZlc7IrYttCxMAFTGxAEwCTuP1b+x1e+MPgX44g8KfFfwrr/
02-25 19:56:53.823: D/Http Response:(29778): AIM8O/HbQrRPBup+IdLu9NgvdasLgTaLLbG6jhPlaj9s+ysWAmL3Gn7
02-25 19:56:53.943: W/dalvikvm(29778): threadid=15: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40d3b2a0)
02-25 19:56:53.978: E/AndroidRuntime(29778): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
02-25 19:56:53.978: E/AndroidRuntime(29778): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
02-25 19:56:53.978: E/AndroidRuntime(29778):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
02-25 19:56:53.978: E/AndroidRuntime(29778):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
02-25 19:56:53.978: E/AndroidRuntime(29778):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
02-25 19:56:53.978: E/AndroidRuntime(29778):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
02-25 19:56:53.978: E/AndroidRuntime(29778):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
02-25 19:56:53.978: E/AndroidRuntime(29778):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
02-25 19:56:53.978: E/AndroidRuntime(29778):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
02-25 19:56:53.978: E/AndroidRuntime(29778):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
02-25 19:56:53.978: E/AndroidRuntime(29778):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
02-25 19:56:53.978: E/AndroidRuntime(29778): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query at index 204: http://ictfox.com/Hafil_Updates/SchoolLocation_Insert.aspx?schoolId=212&Location_Longitude=0&Location_Latitude=0&Location_Image=/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEB
02-25 19:56:53.978: E/AndroidRuntime(29778): AQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQH/2wBDAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEB
02-25 19:56:53.978: E/AndroidRuntime(29778): AQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQH/wAARCABLAGQDASIA
02-25 19:56:53.978: E/AndroidRuntime(29778): AhEBAxEB/8QAHwAAAQUBAQEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL/8QAtRAAAgEDAwIEAwUFBAQA
02-25 19:56:53.978: E/AndroidRuntime(29778): AAF9AQIDAAQRBRIhMUEGE1FhByJxFDKBkaEII0KxwRVS0fAkM2JyggkKFhcYGRolJicoKSo0NTY3
02-25 19:56:53.978: E/AndroidRuntime(29778): ODk6Q0RFRkdISUpTVFVWV1hZWmNkZWZnaGlqc3R1dnd4eXqDhIWGh4iJipKTlJWWl5iZmqKjpKWm
02-25 19:56:53.978: E/AndroidRuntime(29778): p6ipqrKztLW2t7i5usLDxMXGx8jJytLT1NXW19jZ2uHi4+Tl5ufo6erx8vP09fb3+Pn6/8QAHwEA
02-25 19:56:53.978: E/AndroidRuntime(29778): AwEBAQEBAQEBAQAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL/8QAtREAAgECBAQDBAcFBAQAAQJ3AAECAxEEBSEx
02-25 19:56:53.978: E/AndroidRuntime(29778): BhJBUQdhcRMiMoEIFEKRobHBCSMzUvAVYnLRChYkNOEl8RcYGRomJygpKjU2Nzg5OkNERUZHSElK
02-25 19:56:53.978: E/AndroidRuntime(29778): U1RVVldYWVpjZGVmZ2hpanN0dXZ3eHl6goOEhYaHiImKkpOUlZaXmJmaoqOkpaanqKmqsrO0tba3
02-25 19:56:53.978: E/AndroidRuntime(29778): uLm6wsPExcbHyMnK0tPU1dbX2Nna4uPk5ebn6Onq8vP09fb3+Pn6/9oADAMBAAIRAxEAPwD+zn4p
02-25 19:56:53.978: E/AndroidRuntime(29778): fEy+8A3WlRw2Bnt7u7SGeYFlEUZL/MAoYux2n5SME7gGDdfLf2rf2mdQ+A/wF1f4neG9Ih17VLG1
02-25 19:56:53.978: E/AndroidRuntime(29778): tJ4rCSSRYzC86rczyGCOSQi1hEkuxF3yMojVlJzTfjv4z0jVdYh0CEo/9mOJLyXK4WXawWFeT8wB
02-25 19:56:53.978: E/AndroidRuntime(29778): DseoG0Ec5r5P+NPiTw/J8LvEFl4puhLolvptyGt7lswrH5UpdWRz8ygYCochSTgYHP8AiT4pftB8
02-25 19:56:53.978: E/AndroidRuntime(29778): 88KvpLeK/AORQx3iXw3iKvDXDvDVDAyweEw/C/F1KSwme5dQxMKDnj6NWrO1WrOdaths0pV8JCm6
02-25 19:56:53.978: E/AndroidRuntime(29778): Sml/Yfhh4bZFmdfwzxmfcMSx1GnnGDr55lN68anEGW1cZTlHCylTaqUpYilHk/duLdOUZXbab98/
02-25 19:56:53.978: E/AndroidRuntime(29778): Yz/by8F/tGeB7zVtZvtN0PX9MkSHUrE3amN9yeZHc2ryOjyW0oUMG6q3mRNh0YlPiL+2J4dvdR8V
02-25 19:56:53.978: E/AndroidRuntime(29778): eBvDOuWw1JrSaHRbmyu1eWbUY4rh1SMox2tG0akKGJb5hjgmv5afgTo3iXxt4+8QeG/gzDqclpJq
02-25 19:56:53.978: E/AndroidRuntime(29778): V5KselXU1nb22myXk7RrcXEUiBLdiGaOHkAF0RCqNX6OfC34Q+KfDfxY8IeFvEemTafrM11Hqz3s
02-25 19:56:53.978: E/AndroidRuntime(29778): shntk03T3M+pXhuMAsI4dwIfDSSywxBnLZr/AEYhm3G3FGJ4BxWDzTOckoZTn+VZjmWHweGw0qnE
02-25 19:56:53.978: E/AndroidRuntime(29778): UJXjHh/NZV8PXVKjKdWM6ywUqVapiaFKH1h0HVpT/rPxm+hj4J8KZn4lYifFM8mwWZcJ5tmuW8L1
02-25 19:56:53.978: E/AndroidRuntime(29778): auFw+P4UwTyrE18RmOIq1MXPERw+BjGdVTlTvRoQnL2s3CFU/oB+FH7R3hTxD4A0XWPEmoRWmpE2
02-25 19:56:53.978: E/AndroidRuntime(29778): 2nX3DMsl46v5EyhMkLej50AyolLwjLKM9n8TPiff6N4G1bWPAugah4q1xbKWTSNJtfItpL26KSfZ
02-25 19:56:53.978: E/AndroidRuntime(29778): 4vNv57WKJXcJueWRVQMSzYWvkP4fjwt4D0S00fTZI4UQMQwO+6nCHLn92GdljGOVBCA5LDG4+sWX
02-25 19:56:53.978: E/AndroidRuntime(29778): ivRZoRKbmKWN1DLIkqsGXMgO192DgrhsZ5BU4JGf7SzrgeGJzLM55fjK+Cy7ETcsJQhhISxWFjU5
02-25 19:56:53.978: E/AndroidRuntime(29778): 00qjqyhyqXM6CdJuMbRlKThJv/B/w+8asJlnDfCkOJMgwnEPE2VxoxzzF189q0shzp4apFU08LRw
02-25 19:56:53.978: E/AndroidRuntime(29778): NLGxlWpKMcdUhjoe1nOdaj7FShGPzN+z/wDHr9sKPXfH1/8AtAeArbwpoDXWl2PgiKWbTZZm1C9b
02-25 19:56:53.978: E/AndroidRuntime(29778): UJrszNpOrakG02xs7f5JLowS3F8BbZRJ4nXzj9p39rDx34QlTT/CtlqOpX105UyWlpc3+oXMhcht
02-25 19:56:53.978: E/AndroidRuntime(29778): sdrFNLs82WNI4YI1iEjxQxJkhG90+PnjjRLPwpZLa6nDDfprem3MNvvXfdW6NdW9xhC2fLhFykzu
02-25 19:56:53.978: E/AndroidRuntime(29778): y7R8ibhIVJ8v0f4f2vxW1bwd4l0i2vr6bw74m8L+JLq4sT5dosvh7XtL1ptMu712W3IvW09IpLSa
02-25 19:56:53.978: E/AndroidRuntime(29778): UMY3jmKMsZYebknCtDhyccJi8Tjcwp8/tZ4vMYqVfkqOVlJQdFOmpwlazTSaV5JKJ/onwN4kZHxx
02-25 19:56:53.978: E/AndroidRuntime(29778): wTxL475Z4R8FRx+VrNcowvAvD+JxuX8NVs44fyfKq2CwksVjY5rWoV80oYmnipc6ruvmFdqKvUpq
02-25 19:56:53.978: E/AndroidRuntime(29778): P562n7cHxjttZ/sebTfEC+IkuYoIdFuNM1ax1xbx5GWGCPTri1iv1uHYqsaJH5rMflUknP8ARX8C
02-25 19:56:53.978: E/AndroidRuntime(29778): bv4g658Gfh9q/wAU9MOkeOdR8P295r+mMrC5tJp5ZpLOHUEkAZNTGntaHVIW5i1I3UWcLmvRo/E3
02-25 19:56:53.978: E/AndroidRuntime(29778): hljG1z5du4WPE1zZkIh+cf68xsEVck73ZUCqzFgBmvLfGvxv0fSPtFr4ea3vniBE2rTFn02Ft0ij
02-25 19:56:53.978: E/AndroidRuntime(29778): 7Msbhr1sjCsGWIsyiNpScDjxzq5zKnRwuSrAumuarUdSfJyJSXNKpUhThTp6OTTcm20oyb5k/mvE
02-25 19:56:53.978: E/AndroidRuntime(29778): vxBn4pYfJ8syjwxy/g+pga8sVicdh6zrzxDdKpRVOOIeW5fHCYO7dWeGf1ipVrRotT5qdpepzQbQ
02-25 19:56:53.978: E/AndroidRuntime(29778): 2cADnd2wN+SSewHXOTggHgZPwv4o+P8A8RrLxD4z0e28E2FvBo2vato2mz3bvKbqwsdRmtbPWopE
02-25 19:56:53.978: E/AndroidRuntime(29778): vY45v7Ss0W9SBlKxfaIoZAZIJ0futa1HxjrtlLf6xqE8sDW5ujpaahBb3BtgWYlNJieNH4/1YZmk
02-25 19:56:53.978: E/AndroidRuntime(29778): Y7QrM4IrwDVPEXgo2wuotQSaKVFkjaN8qysWPzbuVbJwQcMCCG2kE1HCdLhrNK2OVDMsqz+pho06
02-25 19:56:53.978: E/AndroidRuntime(29778): dbDYOtLELBznUbp1Kk6NWLcavsqkKcpQ9nL9441JWnE+W
02-25 19:56:54.098: D/dalvikvm(29778): GC_CONCURRENT freed 927K, 20% free 32826K/40903K, paused 26ms+5ms, total 103ms
02-25 19:57:03.463: I/Choreographer(29778): Skipped 523 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-25 19:57:03.808: E/WindowManager(29778): Activity com.ictfox.hafil_tc.LocationsActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@420e78e0 that was originally added here
02-25 19:57:03.808: E/WindowManager(29778): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.ictfox.hafil_tc.LocationsActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@420e78e0 that was originally added here
02-25 19:57:03.808: E/WindowManager(29778):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:409)
02-25 19:57:03.808: E/WindowManager(29778):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:312)
02-25 19:57:03.808: E/WindowManager(29778):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:224)
02-25 19:57:03.808: E/WindowManager(29778):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:149)
02-25 19:57:03.808: E/WindowManager(29778):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:559)
02-25 19:57:03.808: E/WindowManager(29778):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:277)
02-25 19:57:03.808: E/WindowManager(29778):     at com.ictfox.hafil_tc.LocationsActivity$2.onClick(LocationsActivity.java:124)
02-25 19:57:03.808: E/WindowManager(29778):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4261)
02-25 19:57:03.808: E/WindowManager(29778):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17330)
02-25 19:57:03.808: E/WindowManager(29778):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
02-25 19:57:03.808: E/WindowManager(29778):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-25 19:57:03.808: E/WindowManager(29778):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-25 19:57:03.808: E/WindowManager(29778):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
02-25 19:57:03.808: E/WindowManager(29778):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-25 19:57:03.808: E/WindowManager(29778):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-25 19:57:03.808: E/WindowManager(29778):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
02-25 19:57:03.808: E/WindowManager(29778):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
02-25 19:57:03.808: E/WindowManager(29778):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-25 19:57:03.973: E/SpannableStringBuilder(29778): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
02-25 19:57:03.973: E/SpannableStringBuilder(29778): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
02-25 19:57:03.973: E/SpannableStringBuilder(29778): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
02-25 19:57:03.973: E/SpannableStringBuilder(29778): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
```

Comment: Post the rest of the stack trace.

Answer (score 2):

You have "/" characters in your query params. Try URL-encoding them as "%2F" (without the quote) using URLEncoder.encode.

```
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://ictfox.com/Hafil_Updates/SchoolLocation_Insert.aspx?schoolId="+((MyApplication) mActivity.getApplication()).schoolNum+"&Location_Longitude="+this.txtLag+"&Location_Latitude="+this.txtLat+"&Location_Image="+URLEncoder.encode(imageString)+"&Action_Date="+date2);
```

This should produce: 
http://ictfox.com/Hafil_Updates/SchoolLocation_Insert.aspx?schoolId=212&Location_Longitude=0&Location_Latitude=0&Location_Image=%2F9j%2F4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD%2F2wBDAAEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEB

[EDIT]
If the image is too big you'll want to submit it in the request body:

```
String url = "http://ictfox.com/Hafil_Updates/SchoolLocation_Insert.aspx";

HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);

List<NameValuePair> urlParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("schoolId", ((MyApplication) mActivity.getApplication()).schoolNum));
urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Location_Longitude", this.txtLag));
urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Location_Latitude", this.txtLat));
urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Location_Image", imageString));
urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Location_Longitude", date2));

post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(urlParameters));

HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
```

Comment: The Base64 encoded image is probably too large to fit in the URL query string. You most likely will have to submit it in the request body. To know how to do this, look at the doc for the HTTP library you are using.

Comment: See http://www.mkyong.com/java/apache-httpclient-examples/ section 2 for an example (if you follow that method you won't need to manually URL-encode the image).

Comment: i can't understand this example, can you please set it for me ?

Answer (score 2):

Base64 encoding uses some characters that are not allowed in URL query parameter values ('/' and '+'). To avoid this, pass `Base64.URL_SAFE` as the second parameter to `Base64.encodeToString()` instead of `Base64.DEFAULT`.

Comment: After doing that I still had to call trim() to remove a \n at the end.